# remove component on button click in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have this structure in app, each level is a component:

```
Assigning
├── Assignee (key='user0')
│   ├── AssigneeTask (key='user0task0')
|   |   └── button (onClick)
│   ├── AssigneeTask (key='user0task1')
|   |   └── button (onClick)
|   └── AssigneeTask (key='user0task2')
|       └── button (onClick)
├── Assignee (key='user1')
└── Assignee (key='user2')
```

I want to remove `Assignee` component when i click on button in it using the key of component, how can i do this in reactjs?
I tried to pass the key to the `onClick` and set the `display` to `none`, but i can't get the component by its key!

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: see updates....

Comment: This depends a bit on your implementation. Can you show the code for `Assigning`?

Comment: Use **refs**. That would solve your problem. Also, you don't really need to access key here. Keys are only used by react internally to identify each node individually. We as a react dev don't really use key per se.

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta there is a reason react gives a warning if you are missing access keys

Comment: @MarvinFischer I think he means not to use key as prop!

Comment: @ZeyadEtman yeah i know, but if you don't use key as a prop react will throw you a warning, they do not do this for no reason.

Comment: @MarvinFischer You have to use the **key** prop for sure. But as far as I know, it is used by React itself for its internal operations, we just have to provide it to react for its proper and efficient functioning. It is not supposed to be used by developers as a component instance identifier. So, you can not pass its value to some function for element identification.

Comment: Ok yeah, thats right. @ZeyadEtman look at the answer below how to access it without the key

Comment: Ok i'll try it. Thanks @MarvinFischer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use state / function uplifting:

```js
class Container extends Component {
    [...]
    render() {
        return this.state.opened && <ContainerButton clickedButton={this.close} />
    }

    close = () => {
        this.setState({opened: false});
    }
}

class ContainerButton extends Component {
    [...]

    render() {
        <button onClick={this.props.clickedButton} />
    }
}
```

If you now trigger the onClick on the button, the close function of `Container` gets triggered